# Are the Arcana Domain cleric's wizard cantrips from Arcane Initiate in addition to every cleric's 3 starting cantrips?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, cleric, cantrips, domains

Are the Arcana Domain cleric's wizard cantrips from the Arcane Initiate feature in addition to the base cleric's 3 starting ones (i.e. 3 cleric cantrips + 2 wizard ones from the Arcana Domain)?

The [Arcana Domain](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#ArcanaDomain) is from the D&D 5e book *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide*. The text of the Arcane Initiate feature (p. 125) says:

> When you choose this domain at 1st level, you gain proficiency in the Arcana skill, and you gain two cantrips of your choice from the wizard spell list. For you, these cantrips count as cleric cantrips.

To me this is vague; I don't know if these two cantrips are a bonus, or an addition to my cantrips list (for cleric) that I can choose from.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, they are extra to his cleric cantrips.

This is right in your quote:

> ... you **gain** two cantrips of your choice from the wizard spell list.

"Gain" is not "substitute".

Comment: This could really use some textual support or background reasoning, rather than a flat yes/no answer.

Answer (score 3):

You gain the cantrips as described in the feature in addition to those provided in the Cleric's spell list. In addition, these function as Cleric cantrips, therefore, you may use your Wisdom mod to determine your attack roll bonus or set your save DC.

We see this addition of cantrips beyond the norm for a class multiple times in the PHB. Off the top of my head, College of Lore Bards, Light Domain Clerics, Circle of the Land Druids, Tome Warlocks, etc.

The somewhat unique aspect of this is that it turns Wizard cantrips into Cleric cantrips, which is kind of uncommon but it does occur regularly with spells, much less commonly with cantrips. A good example would be Knowledge Domain Clerics gaining Identify as a Cleric spell or Grassland Druids casting Haste, both traditionally arcane spells.